# How many children were in the Noonan household?

Tags: caddyshack

In the [**opening scene**](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-6Ri2kr8xJU) of the 1980 film, [***Caddyshack***](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0080487/), we see the Noonan household and are introduced to Danny Noonan, one of the main characters in the film.  Mrs. Noonan (Danny's mother) is walking through the family home waking up all of her children.  There are several children coming out of different rooms in the home while she is walking through the home.  Older children are holding younger children, several children are running around.  It is a chaotic scene.  **The scene in question begins at 1:30** **in the clip**.

Is there any evidence from filmmakers on the exact number of children that Danny Noonan's parents have?

**Note:  Please do not try to count every child in the opening scene of the movie. (it cannot be done as shots move location and the children change in the shot) I'm looking for evidence from filmmakers on an exact number of children.**

Comment: Let's put aside that this is trivial and in no way adds to the appreciation of the film.  What I really want to know - why do you want to know?

Comment: @JasonPSallinger Because I have always wanted to know the answer to this question.  Isn't that what this site is for...to ask questions?  Well, it used to be what this site was for.  Obviously, things have changed.  Sad.

Comment: @steelersquirrel The exact number of kids is unimportant, the joke is that there are constantly more kids appearing from various places. Also, you can easily find the script to this movie online and try to ascertain the exact amount yourself, but I bet there is no exact answer because... it is unimportant.

Comment: @BCdotWEB I found the script.  The script has 6 children, which is obviously incorrect.  It's important to me because I've always wanted to know.   It's got 2 CV on it, so it doesn't really matter

Answer (score 3):

### The premise of your question is flawed.

We know for a fact that not all of the children were parented by the Noonans because one is specifically identified as a nephew. There are also multiple mature women in the household, all of whom may be mothers to some of the children.

### The credits list six.

Apart from Mr. and Mrs. Noonan, there are five named Noonan children in the credits and one "Noonan Child." Since we know at least one of the kids is *not* a Noonan, this may imply that the rest of the children are not Noonans either. **The best evidence-based answer to your question is six kids.**

### Apart from the Noonan parents, there are 15 people in the scenes in question.

It's disingenuous to say "Please do not try to count every child in the opening scene of the movie... it cannot be done." It absolutely can be done. I counted 15 in my first run through and confirmed the number with several careful reviews. Of course, the girl in the shower may have gotten undressed off-camera after a first appearance, which would bring it to 14 instead, but it wasn't that challenging.

### The odds that you'll get a Ramis quote on this are approaching zero.

If Harold Ramis or any of the other filmmakers even knew how many kids were in this scene, it probably wasn't a detail they would remember for later retrospectives. The exact number is not the point of the joke, the chaotic atmosphere of a house with a ridiculous number of kids was the point of the joke. The most commentary you're going to get on the scene today would be a cast or crew member cringing at the not-too-subtle jab at Irish Catholics, not someone waxing philosophical on why 15 kids was what made the scene.

Comment: I will add as a comment: I have been in a household sleeping more than a dozen children. Waking them up all at once is amateur parenting and further evidence that the Noonans themselves have six at most.

Comment: Ramis did have a quote on this on the 25th anniversary edition of the movie.  He spoke with Brian-Doyle Murray who co-wrote the script.  He was telling him about the chaos of the Murray household in the mornings with the 9 Murray children.  Ramis does not state the number of children in the scene.  Not sure why you bothered answering the question if you think it is flawed, but to each their own

Comment: Right, but that's not a Ramis quote that answers your question, is it? And questions with flawed premises can be answered as long as the flaw in the premise is made clear. You're not looking at the number of kids the Noonans had (I gave the best answer for that), you're looking for the number of kids in the scene (I answered that too). You're welcome.